# How to remove duplicate elements from numpy arrays in columns in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have following dataset and numpy array in column B and I want to make "new_column" by removing the duplicated elements of arrays in column B as shown.

```
A   B                                            new Column
1   ["A","a","123","123","A"]                    ["A","a","123"]  
2   ["abc","a","1234","123","abc"]               ["abc","a","1234","123"]
3   ["abcd","abcd","abcd"]                       ["abcd"]
4   ["hello","mello"]                            ["hello","mello"]
5   ["hi","hi","why"]                            ["hi","why"]
```

I am using following codes but they are not giving the desired output.Please help.

```
def u_value(a):
   return np.unique(a)
```

or

```
def ddpe(a):
    a=list(dict.fromkeys(a))
    return a
```

Comment: `df['new'] = df['B'].apply(np.unique)`, NB. it is useless to build a function just to call an other function ;)

Comment: hey,yes but its not working.Instead giving the same value with double brackets like this:[["A","a","123","123","A"]]

Comment: My bet: you have a string ;)

Comment: Yes.I think you are right.In that case,how should it be done

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem values are not lists, but strings, so use `ast.literal_eval` for lists:

```
import ast

def ddpe(a):
   return list(dict.fromkeys(ast.literal_eval(a)))

df['new Column'] = df['B'].apply(ddpe)
```

Comment: Hey,its not working.Its giving the out as this for example for 1st row.[[, ", A, ,, a, 1, 2, 3, ]]

Comment: What is `print (df.B.head().tolist())` ?

Comment: Its ['["A","a","123","123","A"]', '["abc","a","1234","123","abc"]', '["abcd","abcd","abcd"]', '["hello","mello"]', '["hi","hi","why"']

Comment: @Cuckoo - answer was edited.

Comment: I used exactly this:import ast

def ddpe(a):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(ast.literal_eval(a))     Its giving error like:Unexpected EOF

Comment: @Cuckoo - last `)` was misisng

Comment: oh okay.Got it.Thanks